# Copy Data from Excel to fill into Word Templates with Bookmarks

Tags: excel, vba, bookmarks

I have a set of database in Excel and want to copy them into a Word template with bookmarks through VBA. Individual Word Documents will be generated.

Coding please find as below

```
Option Explicit

'change this to where your files are stored
Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\"
Dim wd As New Word.Application
Dim PersonCell As Range

Sub CreateWordDocuments()
  'create copy of Word in memory
  Dim doc As Word.Document
  wd.Visible = True

  Dim PersonRange As Range
  'create a reference to all the people
  Range("A4").Select

  Set PersonRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))

  'for each person in list
  For Each PersonCell In PersonRange
    'open a document in Word
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "Template.docx")
      
    'go to each bookmark and type in details
    CopyCell "FirstName", 1
    CopyCell "LastName", 2
    CopyCell "Company", 3
    CopyCell "Address", 4

    'save and close this document
    doc.SaveAs2 FilePath & "person " & PersonCell.Value & " (" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ").docx"
    doc.Close
  Next PersonCell

  wd.Quit

  MsgBox "Created files in " & FilePath & "!"

  Set doc = Nothing
  Set wd = Nothing
End Sub

Sub CopyCell(BookMarkName As String, ColumnOffset As Integer)
  'copy each cell to relevant Word bookmark
  wd.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkName
  wd.Selection.TypeText PersonCell.Offset(0, ColumnOffset).Value
End Sub
```

Now, I want to generate one Word document with multiple pages. How to modify the coding to generate one word document with multiple pages?

Comment: Word `mail merge` is a good feature for your question. 
_Microsoft documentation:_

> [Mail merge using an Excel spreadsheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461), OR https://helpdesk.concord.edu/kb/article/122-how-to-do-a-mail-merge-in-word-using-an-excel-spreadsheet/

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I know how to use an Excel spreadsheet for mail merging, but I want to using VBA for generating the document.

Comment: It's doable with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Selection.InsertBreak method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertbreak?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158662778)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Selection.EndKey method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.endkey?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158663161)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Selection.WholeStory method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.wholestory?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158663180)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CreateWordDocuments()
    Dim wd As New Word.Application
    '    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim PersonCell As Range
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    'change this to where your files are stored
    Const FilePath As String = "D:\temp\"
    '    Set wd = GetObject(, "word.application") ' for testing
    wd.Visible = True
    Dim PersonRange As Range
    'create a reference to all the people
    Set PersonRange = Range(Range("A4"), Range("A4").End(xlDown))
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "Template.docx")
    ' Copy the contents of template doc
    wd.Selection.WholeStory
    wd.Selection.Copy
    wd.Selection.Delete
    'for each person in list
    For Each PersonCell In PersonRange
        'paste the template at the end of doc
        wd.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        If wd.Selection.End > 0 Then
            wd.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
        End If
        wd.Selection.Paste
        'go to each bookmark and type in details
        CopyCell "FirstName", 1, PersonCell, wd
        CopyCell "LastName", 2, PersonCell, wd
        CopyCell "Company", 3, PersonCell, wd
        CopyCell "Address", 4, PersonCell, wd
    Next PersonCell
    'save and close this document
    doc.SaveAs2 FilePath & "person(" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ").docx"
    doc.Close
    wd.Quit
    MsgBox "Created files in " & FilePath & "!"
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing
End Sub
Sub CopyCell(ByVal BookMarkName As String, ByVal ColumnOffset As Integer, ByVal PersonCell As Range, wd As Word.Application)
    'copy each cell to relevant Word bookmark
    wd.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkName
    wd.Selection.TypeText PersonCell.Offset(0, ColumnOffset).Value
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Update:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CreateWordDocuments()
    Dim wd As New Word.Application
    '    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim PersonCell As Range
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    'change this to where your files are stored
    Const FilePath As String = "D:\temp\"
    '    Set wd = GetObject(, "word.application") ' for testing
    wd.Visible = True
    Dim PersonRange As Range
    'create a reference to all the people
    With Sheets("Sheet1") ' ** '
        Set PersonRange = .Range("A4", .Range("A4").End(xlDown)) ' ** '
    End With ' ** '
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "Template.docx")
    ' Copy the contents of template doc
    wd.Selection.WholeStory
    wd.Selection.Copy
    wd.Selection.Delete
    'for each person in list
    For Each PersonCell In PersonRange
        'paste the template at the end of doc
        wd.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        If wd.Selection.End > 0 Then
            wd.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
        End If
        wd.Selection.Paste
        'go to each bookmark and type in details
        CopyCell "FirstName", 1, PersonCell, wd
        CopyCell "LastName", 2, PersonCell, wd
        CopyCell "Company", 3, PersonCell, wd
        CopyCell "Address", 4, PersonCell, wd
        Call RemoveBMs(doc)
    Next PersonCell
    'save and close this document
    doc.SaveAs2 FilePath & "person(" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ").docx"
    doc.Close
    wd.Quit
    MsgBox "Created files in " & FilePath & "!"
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing
End Sub
Sub CopyCell(ByVal BookMarkName As String, ByVal ColumnOffset As Integer, ByVal PersonCell As Range, wd As Word.Application)
    'copy each cell to relevant Word bookmark
    wd.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkName
    wd.Selection.TypeText PersonCell.Offset(0, ColumnOffset).Value
End Sub
Sub RemoveBMs(doc As Word.Document)
    Dim oBM As Bookmark
    Const BM_NAME = "FirstName|LastName|Company|Address"
    For Each oBM In doc.Bookmarks
        If InStr(1, BM_NAME, oBM.Name, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then _
        oBM.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Taller, thank you for your kind assistance. I have already followed your coding. A file could be generated successfully, but all data from Excel Database were copied to the bookmark on the first page of word document. No data were copied to the second page, third page ...... I don't know why the output is different from yours.

Comment: I've tested the code on Office 365. How about yours? I think your bookmarks weren't deleted after updating. It shouldn't be like that. Anyway, I've updated the code to fix it. Please try.

Comment: Dear Taller, I highly appreciation your help. I am using Microsoft Excel 2016 in my office.... I am responsible for supporting my colleagues who ae not good at computering. They are afraid of using Microsoft Word bulti-in function Mail Merge Document, so I want to create an Excel VBA by clicking a button to generate it.

Comment: Dear Taller, I have tried but failed at the Sub RemoveBMs. At Row Cont BM_Name = "FirstName|LastName|Company|Address" , BM_Name - "Variable not defined".  Maybe my excel version is not up-to-date, so many problems occur...... I am so sorry.

Comment: After executing the VBA, the Word Template was opened and the first row of data was copied to the bookmark. Then VBA was stopped and showed the message box that "Variable not defined" at BM_Name of "Cont BM_Name = "FirstName|LastName|Company|Address"

Comment: It's a typo. Try `Const BM_NAME ... `

Comment: Taller, Thank You for Very Kind Assistance. The VBA really works.

Comment: Excuse me, Taller.  I have a question on this VBA Coding. If I have inserted one more spreadsheet, will an additional spreadsheet affect the VBA operating?

Comment: It depends. I've revised the code of `'create a reference to all the people` to make it more reliable. You file with new inserted sheet works well.

Comment: Excuse Sir Taller. I have faced a new situation.  I have used IFERROR, INDEX and SMALL Function to filter out some data (Equation: {=IFERRPR(IF(INDEX(Range,SMALL(IF(<Citeria = Company>=Range,ROW(Range)-2,""),ROW()-ROW(34)))=0,"//",INDEX(Range,SMALL(IF(<Citeria>=Range,ROW(Range)-2,""),ROW()-ROW(34)))),"")}, which are matched the citeria. If the Full List has 30 rows, after IFERROR, INDEX and SMALL function was executed, only seven rows were filtered out.  Then VBA will generate 23 pages empty templates.  Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Dear Taller, sorry to disturb you.

Comment: No worry. You'll get supports from SO users whenever you post a question.